# List custom wordpress user meta based on id

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get custom meta data from all users. I have the following code the returns no errors. So I don't know what is going wrong. Is there a more simple way to loop over all id's and return custom meta data?

```
global $wpdb;
$wp_user_search = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users ORDER BY ID");

foreach ($wp_user_search as $userid) {
    $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta($userid->id);

    $email_alert = $all_meta_for_user['email_sms'][0];

    echo $email_alert;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular WordPress functions.

In this case, [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users).

Like this:

```
$wp_user_search = get_users( 'blog_id=1&orderby=id' );

foreach ( $wp_user_search as $userid ) 
{
    $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta($userid->ID);
    $email_alert = $all_meta_for_user['email_sms'][0];
    echo $email_alert;
}
```

Also note that you were using `$userid->id`, instead of **`$userid->ID`**.

For checking the values of your variables use:

- `var_dump($userid)`
- or `echo '<pre>' . print_r( $all_meta_for_user, true ) . '</pre>';`