# how can I display all info on wp_users and wp_usermeta on user logged in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

how can I display all info on user when logged in,

like

first name
last Name
email

custom field
-address
-telephone

I got here a line of code and I dont know what to do with it

```
$all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta( userid );
```

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558075/list-custom-wordpress-user-meta-based-on-id

Answer (score 0):

function which can used is [get_currentuserinfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo) to get current logged in user details.

function used to custom fields of user is [get_user_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

```
<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
      echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
      echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
      echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
?>
```

Once you get logged in user id , you can use get_user_meta to get details.

```
<?php
  $all_meta_for_user = get_user_meta($current_user->ID );
  print_r( $all_meta_for_user );
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot. got another question

can I convert this script <?php echo $all_meta_for_user['address'][0]; ?> into a javascript so that I could insert it into the value


<input type="text" size="40" value="" name="your-email">

for example

<input type="text" size="40" value="insert the script here" name="your-email">

because Im using contact form 7 and it does not allow php inside

Comment: yes you can <script> var emailaddress = <?php echo $all_meta_for_user['address'][0]; ?> </script>

and you can use "emailaddress" variable in js.. not sure whether its correct method or not..